# How to access xml layout in custom button

Tags: android, xml, layout, button

i'd appreciate any help with following.

i have created a custom component - MyButton class that extends Button. I can set attributes in the constructor but i don't want to do this. i would like to set attributes in xml layout file. how do i get the attributes into the constructor so that when i create a new button in an activity, the new button is created using the xml layout file?

i've tried using inflator but it does not work in class extending button. is there another way that does the same? - i've spent hours searching net but nothing satisfactory came up.

thanks in advance

clive

here's the code

```
public class CustomViewModify2Activity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    MyButton myb = (MyButton)findViewById(R.id.mybutton1);
    myb.setText("hello");
}
```

}

the class:

```
public class MyButton extends Button {

public MyButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Red));
}

public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);      
    this.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Yellow));
}
```

}

the main.xml`

```
    <idig.za.net.MyButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mybutton1"
    />
```

`

the button_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/my_button_layout">
<Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/Yellow" android:gravity="center"
    android:width="100dp" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColorLink="@color/Red"></Button>
```

Comment: post the xml from your layout file

Comment: Have you looked at this tutorial ? http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/05/02/android-tutorial-42-passing-custom-variables-via-xml-resource-files/

Comment: hi, yes i have but i find it a bit confusing. i tried manipulating my code as per their example but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the xml you can specify

```
<packagename.MyButton
```

instead of

```
<Button
```

and you will be able to specify attributes as if it were a normal button. That's what i did in my app.

Comment: tried pocketJourney solution mention above. i can get the attributes individually (in a typedArray) but to assign them to the new button (MyButton) as a collection, they need to be in a AttributeSet (as per constructor). is it possible to convert from TypedArray to AttributeSet? or do i have to assign each attribute individually in my class?

Answer (score 0):

```
 XmlPullParser parser = resources.getXml(myResouce);
 AttributeSet attributes = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
```

and then call the second constructor.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/AttributeSet.html

Comment: No no. call the second constructor like `new MyButton(getApplicationContext(), attributes);`

Comment: thanks for your help but i'm a bit of an idiot and would appreciate it if you could not be so cryptic in your replies. i'm new at this android stuff and am trying to learn as i go. thanks again.

Comment: this is what i added to the 2nd constructor but no luck:  XmlPullParser parser = resources.getXml(myResouce);
   AttributeSet attributes = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
   new MyButton(getApplicationContext(), attributes);

Comment: Ow, sorry, I always assume someone has some programmer knowledge regardless if it is for android or not. :) My pleasure helping you. :)